# Download manager not working properly in fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-webview, download-manager

I am trying to download a file stored in a cloud storage site internxt using file url from a webview in android. file is opening in webview. but unable to download. app stopped working when clicked download & downloaded 100%.

Logcat showing error like following
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not handle uri:: blob:https://share.internxt.com/38f153b9-c64e-4516-9335-f75f59137546

please help me to download the file

Here is my source code

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    String URL = "http://nregsorders.co.in/index.php";

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();


        return root;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        WebView web = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.Webview1);

        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        web.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web.loadUrl(URL);

        web.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {
            //    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              //  i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
              //  startActivity(i);
                        DowloadDialog(url,userAgent,contentDisposition,mimetype);
            }
        });




    }

    public void DowloadDialog(final String url, final String UserAgent, String contentdisposition, String mimetype)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(requireView().getContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentdisposition,mimetype);
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireView().getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Downloading...")
                .setMessage("Do you want to Download "+ ' '+" "+filename+" "+' ')
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,filename);
                        long reference = manager.enqueue(request);
                    }

                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals(URL)) {
                // This is your web site, so do not override; let the WebView to load the page
                return false;
            }


            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }



        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);

            // this will ignore the Ssl error and will go forward to your site
            handler.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

i just need to download the file when clicking the download button from the webview link